# JSONObject["data"] not found in Test (Junit5)

Tags: java, json

I am new to programming and am trying to use `JSONObject`
. But I have a problem.
I have a class:

```
public HttpResponse session() {

    String url = Enviroment.API.getUrl() + "/session";
    HttpResponse<String> response;
    try {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Cookie", "_token=eyJ")
                .GET()
                .build();
        response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    assertEquals("ErrorCode: 3.3", new JSONObject(response.body()).getJSONObject("data").get("error"));
    return response;
}
```

and I have a test:

```
@Test

void test001GetSession(){

    HttpResponse response = new Session().session();
    assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 400);
    assertEquals("ErrorCode: 3.3", new JSONObject(response.body()).getJSONObject("data").get("error"));
    assertEquals("error", new JSONObject(response.body()).get("message"));
    assertEquals(false, new JSONObject(response.body()).get("status"));

}
```

and result of my test is

> "org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["data"] not found.

" But same string in class works without problem. Why?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `response.body()`?

Comment: In class or test?

Comment: Why my question is closed? Where is duplicate?

Comment: `In class or test?` both please.

Comment: Don't mind please. I decided this problem.